# Opencv Raspberry python3

Tags: opencv

I want to use Opencv3 with my raspberryPi, but when I open the camera, and I test it, it's right that, don't work

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while 1:
    if cap.isOpened():
        print("Work")
    else:
        print("Don't work)
```

Comment: Did you enable the camera in `raspi-config`? Did you load the Broadcom v4l2 module with `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`

Comment: Yeah I enable the camera, and the broadcome v412 return an error modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.50-v7+/modules.dep.bin'

Comment: Can you shoot still, single frames with `raspistill`?

Comment: Its work fine, I must use "sudo rpi-update" and after "sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2"

Comment: Good! You can add it to `/etc/modules` so it is loaded at every boot.

Comment: I have summarised everything we have learned in an answer for future readers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you want to use the camera on a Raspberry Pi, you should probably do the following:

---

**Step 1 - Enable camera in raspi-config**

Start `raspi-config` with:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and find the command to enable the camera - it differs from version to version. Enable the camera and allow the reboot.

---

**Step 2 - Update the Raspberry Pi firmware**

It's generally a good idea to ensure that the firmware is up-to-date so the latest, greatest kernel and drivers work.

```
sudo rpi-update
```

A reboot is required after that.

---

**Step 3 - Check the camera can shoot still images**

You can check this with `raspistill` to take a photo as follows:

```
raspistill -o picture.jpg
```

---

**Step 4 - Configure v4l2**

If you additionally want to use **OpenCV** and shoot video, you will need to ensure that the `v4l2` *"Video for Linux"* module is installed. You can do that with:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

If that loads correctly, your should be able to access video from the camera in OpenCV. Rather than repeating the command after every boot, you can add a single line to the bottom of `/etc/modules` so it looks like this:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.


# SETCHELL v4l2 added for OpenCV video capture
bcm2835-v4l2
```

I generally put my surname in any system files I edit then I can easily find any files I have dinked around with if I make a mess, and I can also back them up, and also tell anyone I help out on StackOverflow of any system changes I have made - yes, I am a bit OCD!

---

If it still doesn't work, check your cable is correct - the silver connector must face the HDMI port.

**Keywords**: Raspberry Pi, raspi, RPi, camera, camera cable, still, photo, video, OpenCV, v4l, v4l2, Video for Linux, raspi-config, raspistill, rpi-update, bcm2835, bcm2835-v4l2, modules, modprobe