# Raspberry pi 3B OpenCV 3.4.1 Empty screen/frame

Tags: opencv, camera, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am new to StackOverflow in that this is my first post. I am hoping that I am abiding by the rules as such and that I am not frustrating anyone with me double-posting an issue.

My problem is the following. I was able to compile and install OpenCV 3.4.1. on my Raspberry Pi 3B. The only problem I was not able to solve is that when I test the camera (by viewing the cam-feed through OpenCV) I get an empty frame. Rarely it does flicker, and show the actual camera feed.

I have a screenshot to show what I mean:

[image]

What you can also see is that when I make a image, by using the video.py script and pressing "enter", it **does** produce the correct image. When I move the frame around (with the cursor) it seems to be flickering more (revealing the actual camera feed more often) than usual. I have tried reinstalling NOOBS, recompiling and reinstalling more times than I can recall. What could the problem be? If I missed sharing relevant information, please let me know!

Thank you soooo much for your time!
Kind regards, Pieter

Edit: Here is the print-out when running opencv_version -v in the terminal

```
opencv_version -v

General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.1 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2018-09-29T19:02:09Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.14.71-v7+ armv7l
    CMake:                       3.7.2
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RELEASE

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:
      requested:                 DETECT
      disabled:                  VFPV3 NEON

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++11:                       YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 6.3.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      
    Linker flags (Debug):        
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann highgui imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator ml objdetect photo python3 python_bindings_generator shape stitching superres video videoio videostab
    Disabled:                    js python2 world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java ts viz
    Applications:                examples apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    GTK+:                        YES (ver 2.24.31)
      GThread :                  YES (ver 2.50.3)
      GtkGlExt:                  NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so (ver )
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng.so (ver 1.6.28)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.8)
    JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.64.101)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.56.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.34.101)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
    gPhoto2:                     NO

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (built-in)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/pi/opencv-3.4.1/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.3)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.3)
    numpy:                       /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.15.2)
    packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        NO

  Install to:                    /usr/local
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have a feeling, that you are missing the actual code in your question

Comment: There's a little checklist here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44240568/2836621

Comment: Also, your compilation should have produced an executable called `opencv_version` so try finding that and running it with `-v` parameter and pasting the output into your question - click `edit` under your question to edit it.

Comment: Hi Dmitrii Z.; I am not quite following. What code are you referring too? Do you want me to show the webcam.py of OpenCV? It should be the standard script, but if you want I can print it out.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, been there, done it, got a t-shirt. Everything works in that sense. I have webcam connection. It really is only that the frame is empty. As mentioned before, the webcam operates and I can make picture with the webcam.py script

Comment: @MarkSetchell, that a great command. I hope the print out is useful to you..

Comment: I reinstalled everything and now it seems to work. I will post an image of this shortly too.