# raspberry camera module driver for opencv issue

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I use Raspberry camera module in opencv with `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` because of that I install `Video4Linux` driver with this command:
`sudo apt-get -y install libv4l-dev v4l-utils`
`sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`
but I have a problem; I have run in command every time that boot Raspberry.
how to solve it?

Comment: what does `I have run in command every time that boot Raspberry` mean

Comment: You can load it automagically like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44240568/2836621