# How do I specify the video port instead of still port in opencv on a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, picamera

When I use PiCamera, I have capture stills or video. [They describe](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html#the-video-port) that there is a difference between the two. I find stills are slower when capturing continuously. Video is a faster frame rate.

When I use VideoCapture in OpenCV, it seems to capture at the similar rate of continuous stills. I have an [example python script](https://gist.github.com/saltzmanjoelh/8e8c2029581df349cadc20157efe5b8b) to show my findings. I tested 5 seconds of capture on a Sony IMX219 at a resolution of 1920X1080:

- PiCamera Video: 146 frames at **28.81fps** fileSize: **75KB**
- PiCamera Stills: 8 frames at **1.78fps** fileSize: **12.3 MB**
- OpenCV VideoCapture: 14 frames at **3.12fps** fileSize: **670KB**

In all three cases, I tried to optimize by not writing to disk and just capture in memory to rule out disk I/O.

Is there another setting in OpenCV that I should be using like it appears that PiCamera is doing?

@MarkSetchell, Setting the CAP_PROP_FPS seems to have no effect.

@MarkSetchell, Running opencv first doesn't make a difference. I noticed this on a system that didn't even have picamera installed. Example script has been updated though.

@MarkSetchell, [cv2.getBuildInformation()](https://gist.github.com/saltzmanjoelh/48a71d5c95052d463b93cd8f947561ed)

@MarkSetchell, If I enable file creation the picamera stills are larger than opencv. I listed the file sizes above

Does this mean bcm2835_v4l2 is loaded but not being used?
lsmod | grep

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bcm2835_v4l2           45056  0
cm2835_v4l2            45056  0
v4l2_mem2mem           24576  1 bcm2835_codec
bcm2835_mmal_vchiq     32768  2 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  3 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem
videobuf2_common       45056  4 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              200704  6 bcm2835_codec,v4l2_common,videobuf2_common,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf    2_v4l2 media                  36864  3 bcm2835_codec,videodev,v4l2_mem2mem
```

Comment: Line 65 needs removing - you shouldn't be setting the framerate in the middle of your acquisition! Also, your indentation is up the spout.

Comment: Try running the OpenCV capture first, in case running Raspicam stills has set something that OpenCV doesn't clear.

Comment: Try printing output of `cv2.getBuildInformation()`.

Comment: Check this too... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44240568/2836621

Comment: I can't see what's going wrong, though I note the first 2 are just getting JPEGs which are probably 200kB whereas OpenCV is grabbing 6MB of high quality image per frame.

Comment: No, I was referring to the volume of data that OpenCV reads from the camera. If you read a 2000x1000 pixel image with 3 bytes per pixel into an OpenCV Numpy array you will have received 6MB from the camera. If you read a 2000x1000 pixel MJPEG-compressed image from the camera that's probably under 200kB, i.e. 30x less.